# Place content between headers in LaTeX environments using a lua filter

Tags: lua, pandoc

Consider this markdown file:

```
#

This is text below a h1 header

##

This is text below a h2 header

#

This is text below a h1 header

##

This is text below a h2 header
```

I wonder if it would be possible to grab content below a h1 header and put it in a latex environment A and content below a h2 header in environment B using a lua filter.

Something like this:

```lua
function Header(el)
  local beginEnv, endEnv

  if ( el.level == 1 ) then
    beginEnv = "\\begin{A}"
    endEnv = "\\end{A}"
  elseif ( el.level == 2 ) then
    beginEnv = "\\begin{B}"
    endEnv = "\\end{B}"
  end

  -- grab all of the content below the respective header
  -- in the case of the h1 header it should be: "This is text below a h1 header"
  -- in the case of the h2 header it should be: "This is text below a h2 header"
  local contentBelowHeader = ???

  table.insert( contentBelowHeader, 1, pandoc.RawBlock("latex", beginEnv .. "\n" ))
  table.insert( contentBelowHeader, pandoc.RawBlock("latex", "\n" .. endEnv ))

  return el
end
```

The output should be something like (tex file):

```tex
...

\begin{A}
  This is text below a h1 header
\end{A}

\begin{B}
  This is text below a h2 header
\end{B}

\begin{A}
  This is text below a h1 header
\end{A}

\begin{B}
  This is text below a h2 header
\end{B}

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to traverse the whole document and insert the `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}`.

```lua
function latex(str)
  return pandoc.RawInline('latex', str)
end

function Pandoc(doc)
  local blocks = {}
  local pending_end_env = nil

  for i, el in pairs(doc.blocks) do
    if el.t == "Header" then
      if el.level == 1 then
        -- Insert end of last environment if needed
        if pending_end_env then
          table.insert(blocks, latex(pending_end_env))
        end
        -- Insert begin of new environment
        table.insert(blocks, latex('\\begin{A}'))
        -- Store the end of new environment for later use
        pending_end_env = '\\end{A}'
      elseif el.level == 2 then
        -- Same as the el.level == 1 case above
        if pending_end_env then
          table.insert(blocks, latex(pending_end_env))
        end
        table.insert(blocks, latex('\\begin{B}'))
        pending_end_env = '\\end{B}'
      end
    else
      -- Keep all non-header elements as-is
      table.insert(blocks, el)
    end
  end

  -- Close the last environment
  if pending_end_env then
    table.insert(blocks, latex(pending_end_env))
  end

  return pandoc.Pandoc(blocks, doc.meta)
end
```

With this filter, pandoc produces the following tex file from the example markdown in the question.

```latex
\begin{A}

This is text below a h1 header

\end{A}

\begin{B}

This is text below a h2 header

\end{B}

\begin{A}

This is text below a h1 header

\end{A}

\begin{B}

This is text below a h2 header

\end{B}
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you! I have made a few changes: I used a list to store all environments `local envs = { 'A', 'B' }` and in the first if statement inside the for loop I just added a condition `if el.t == 'Header' and envs[el.level] then`. This way I can just add whatever environment is at that index (if anything, else nil), so it could be extended with even more environments and header levels without code duplication. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

With the great help of [@kotatsuyaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12122460/kotatsuyaki), I was able to find a solution to my problem:

```lua
function Pandoc(doc)
  local blocks = {}
  local pending_end_env = nil
  -- Latex environments where each index corresponds to a header level (level 1 == 'A')
  local envs = { 'A', 'B' }

  for _, el in pairs(doc.blocks) do
    -- Check if element is a header and if there exists an environment in envs at header level
    if (el.t == "Header"  and envs[el.level]) then
      -- Insert end of last environment if needed
      if pending_end_env then
        table.insert(blocks, pandoc.RawBlock('latex', pending_end_env ))
      end
      -- Insert begin of new environment
      table.insert(blocks, pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\begin{' .. envs[el.level] .. '}' ))
      -- Store the end of new environment for later use
      pending_end_env = '\\end{' .. envs[el.level] .. '}'
    else
      -- Keep all non-header elements as-is
      table.insert(blocks, el)
    end
  end

  -- Close the last environment
  if pending_end_env then
    table.insert(blocks, pandoc.RawBlock('latex', pending_end_env))
  end

  return pandoc.Pandoc(blocks, doc.meta)
end
```

Most of the code comes from [@kotatsuyaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12122460/kotatsuyaki).

Comment: Great extensibility!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the environments to contain *all* contents below a section, then checkout pandoc's utility function `pandoc.utils.make_sections`: it wraps all headings and the corresponding contents in Div with class `section`. This allows to do

```lua
function Pandoc(doc)
  -- Latex environments where each index corresponds to a header level
  -- (level 1 == 'A')
  local envs = { 'A', 'B' }

  doc.blocks = pandoc.utils.make_sections(false, nil, doc.blocks)
  return doc:walk {
    Div = function (div)
      local heading = div.content[1]
      if div.classes:includes 'section' and heading and heading.level then
        local begin_env = '\\begin{' .. envs[heading.level] .. '}'
        local end_env = '\\end{' .. envs[heading.level] .. '}'
        div.content:insert(2, pandoc.RawBlock('latex', begin_env))
        div.content:insert(pandoc.RawBlock('latex', end_env))
      end
      return div.content
    end
  }
end
```

The output is different from what you want though, as it will be of the pattern

```latex
\section{...}

\begin{A}

This is text below a h1 header

\subsection{...}

\begin{B}

This is text below a h2 header

\end{B}

\end{A}
```

Comment: Very interesting! Is it possible to suppress the blank lines after `\begin` and before `\end`?

Comment: @Jander Only with very considerable extra work in the filter. It's a long-standing pandoc issue.